# Using the C# indexOf() method and it does not work

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am using IndexOf() and it does not work.

The code is:

```
  if (sqlex.Message.IndexOf("Critical") > 0)
```

and Message does contain the word - Critical (see image), but does not equate to true. It takes the false path.

I also put in test code:

```
  int index = sqlex.Message.IndexOf("Critical");
```

and index is = 0.

Why?

[image]

Comment: "Critical".IndexOf("Critical") ==0 - why? just because.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method string.IndexOf returns -1 if the character or string is not found. 0 means it is found. Change your code to if (sqlex.Message.IndexOf("Critical") >= 0)

Answer (score 2):

The first position in the string is 0, not 1. So if your string is

```
Critical Error - do not continue. Contact IT...
```

And you search for `Critical`, then `0` is the expected result.

[If the string is not found, the result will be `-1`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.indexof?view=netcore-3.1#System_String_IndexOf_System_String_) ... unless the string is also empty, so make sure to check that, too.

Comment: You might want to clarify that _unless the string is also empty_ is referring to the search string and not the string being searched.